# Is it true that in a metric space the union of a countable collection of sets in $X$ which are of the first category also of the first category?

Tags: general-topology

Could somebody please check my working on this problem?

Let $X$ be a complete metric space. Is it true that the union of a countable collection of sets in $X$ which are of the first category also of the first category?

My working:

Let $Y$ be any union of a countable collection of sets in $X$ which are of the first category. Then $Y=\cup F$ where $F$ is a countable collection of sets in $X$ which are of the first category. Then the elements of $F$ is a collection of sets which can be written as $E=\cup E_n$ where any $E_n$ is a nowhere dense subset in $X$.

Then it implies $Y$ can also be written as $Y=\cup E_n$.

I know probably my working is not rigorous enough and could be wrong. Could someone help check and correct my working please? How should I fix my working and is there any better way to solve the problem?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: No, I think it's fine, except that you should mention that a countable collection of countable sets is also countable, because that's what makes $Y$ into a *countable* collection of nowhere dense sets. That's all the rest of the proof is a canter.

Comment: Agreed. The presentation needs some improvement but the idea is right.

Answer (score 0):

Write $F=\{G_n:n\in N\}.$ (It does not matter whether $G_{n'}=G_n$ when $n'\ne n.$)  Write $G_n=\cup_{m\in N} \{E_{n,m}\},$ where each  $\; \overline {E_{n,m}} \;$ has empty interior.

(1).Let $f:N\to N\times N$ be a bijection. Then $\cup F=\cup  \{E_{f(j)} :j\in N\}$ is first category.

(2).Or just point out that a countable union of countable sets is countable, so $H=\cup_{n\in N}G_n=\{E_{n,m}:n,m\in N\}$ is countable, so $\cup H$ is first category, and (of course) $\cup H =\cup F.$

Comment: Do you require that *X* be a complete metric space?  It seems to me, supported by your answer, that the claim is true for all metric spaces.

Comment: @user0 . It's true for any space $X$.